# 3D multidimensional array to "row" pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I was wondering how i can access multidimensional rows in a 3D via pointer like this:

```
int ccc[8][7][2] = ....;

for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    int** cc_i = ccc[i];
    for(int j=0;j<7;j++)
    {
        int* c_j = cc_i[j];
        int th0 = c_j[0];
        int th1 = c_j[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because a pointer to a pointer is not the same as an array of arrays. The layout in memory is radically different.

You can however declare e.g. `cc_i` as a pointer to an array, like

```
int (*cc_i)[2] = ccc[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
int ccc[8][7][2] = ....;

for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    int (*cc_i)[2] = ccc[i];
    for(int j=0;j<7;j++)
    {
        int *c_j = cc_i[j];
        int th0 = c_j[0];
        int th1 = c_j[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to try out those pointer declarations, they are not quite correct.

Comment: Performance wise, is this faster or actually accessing by ccc[i][j][0]?

Comment: @BlackCat Why don't you try both ways, and benchmark it to find out? Both with and without optimizations.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes sorry got myself confused